# How to add image and text together in iPhone Navigation bar

Tags: iphone, image, text, uinavigationbar

How can I add image and text together in an iPhone Navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a view controller, you can ask for self.navigationController.navigationBar and add subviews to that.

Or, you can wrap image/text into a UIView, and create a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view set to that combination.

Answer (score 1):

For my answer, I'm assuming you want to show an image in the NavBar with the text prompt above  it - in which case, you'd be looking to use the prompt property on the UINavigationItem class.